# How to pass and modify a agent-set inside a procedure in Net-Logo?

Tags: parameter-passing, netlogo, procedure

I wanted to simplify the way of adding a turtle to a agent-set (not breed)

So I tried:

```
to join-turtles [a-set]
  set a-set (turtle-set a-set self)
end
```

And then I could do:

```
ask some-turtle [join-turtles specific-set]
```

But it doesn't work. It appears to work inside the procedure but the set remains empty after the procedure.

Why? And how do I fix  this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way that NetLogo deals with procedure arguments.  Arguments are passed by value, not by reference, so when you change `a-set` within the procedure the change is made to the "copy" of the argument used by the procedure, not to the argument itself.  In general, you cannot use a procedure to modify its arguments, procedures can only use them.

But, you could make your procedure a reporter, such as

```
to-report join-turtles [a-set]
  set a-set (turtle-set a-set self)
  report a-set
end
```

and then

```
ask target [set t-set join-turtles t-set]
```

I'm not sure how much of a simplification that would be, howerver.

Charles